# How can i define PDO_MYSQL in application.ini file

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpmyadmin, zend-studio, zend-db-table

I am try to connect mysql to zend appllication but its gives exception : SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user '*user*'@'*host*' (using password: YES)

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.isDefaultAdapter = true
resources.db.params.host = *host*
resources.db.params.username = *user*
resources.db.params.password = *password*
resources.db.params.dbname = *dbname*
```

Above noted entry is only in application.ini.
This code is run on localhost in my PC but not on server.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have access to login to Mysql server with that username and password.
Check in phpMyAdmin if user rdvscoin_main has enough privilege to access the database rdvscoin_corporate.

If the Mysql server is on a separate machine check if user can login from the machine where your code is located.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code like this:

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.isDefaultAdapter = true
resources.db.params.host = *host* (put localhost here assuming server host is also localhost)
resources.db.params.username = *user* (put the user name which you used in your database)
resources.db.params.password = *password* (put the password you used in your database)
resources.db.params.dbname = *dbname* (use the database you are using)
```

Hope it works!